# How to use h5py to open .mat file (v7.3) in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I want to load a .mat file (v7.3) which includes a matrix named 'A' from MATLAB. I've made it on my own computer with WIN7-64bit, Python 3.5.2 | Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit), h5py 2.6.0 and numpy (1.12.1+MKL). The commands used are shown below:

```
import numpy as np    
import h5py

filepath='../../xxx.mat'
with h5py.File(filepath, 'r') as f:
x = f['A'][()]
```

However, this failed on another 64-bit computer with Ubuntu 14.04LTS, Python 2.7.6, h5py 2.6.0 and numpy (1.12.0). And the error log is shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readmat_test.py", line 9, in <module>
    with h5py.File(filepath, 'r') as f:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 272, in __init__
    fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, swmr=swmr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 92, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/tmp/pip_build_root/h5py/h5py/_objects.c:2850)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/tmp/pip_build_root/h5py/h5py/_objects.c:2808)
  File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 76, in h5py.h5f.open (/tmp/pip_build_root/h5py/h5py/h5f.c:2096)
IOError: Unable to open file (Unable to find a valid file signature)
```

I'm realy a newbie of Python and just dont know why this happens. Is this caused by the different versions of packages or different OS ? Or any other reasons ?

Many thanks in advance for your help : )

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Just in case you dont get a solution, there is always [`scipy.io.loadmat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html)

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks Ander, but is this command effective for v7.3 file of MATLAB? Sorry for my fault of missing that point. I'll update my question.

Comment: If you read the wwebpage linked, it ends like "v4 (Level 1.0), v6 and v7 to 7.2 matfiles are supported."